# Heroku Sinatra application repeatedly crashing and can't use console

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I'm having trouble with a Sinatra application which I'm trying to deploy to Heroku - this is my first time with Sinatra and Heroku.

I have a .gems file with one line: "sinatra" as well as a config.ru file with the following lines:

```
require 'myapplication'
run Sinatra::Application
```

After pushing to heroku and navigating to the url I receive a page that says "App Crashed" and the following text:

> This application is temporarily
>   offline. If you're the administrator
>   of this app, please check your heroku
>   logs for the backtrace.

The output from "heroku logs" is:

```
2011-02-10T01:33:24-08:00 app[web.1]:   from ./myapplication.rb:3
2011-02-10T01:33:24-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in gem_original_require'
2011-02-10T01:33:24-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:inrequire'
2011-02-10T01:33:24-08:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:2
<-- TEXT SNIPPED -->
2011-02-10T01:33:24-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1:in `new'
2011-02-10T01:33:24-08:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:1
2011-02-10T01:33:25-08:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-02-10T01:33:32-08:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 75.56.61.69 | 3310 | http | 500
```

Where the 3rd line of the myapplication.rb is a "require 'models'" where "models.rb" exists in the same directory as "myapplication.rb".

Also whenever I run the "heroku console" command, I receive the following:

```
Your application is too busy to open a console session.
Console sessions require an open dyno to use for execution.
```

I've tried various options to try to get this to go away but haven't succeeded yet.

Thanks for any help offered!

Comment: If SO doesn't help you might try: http://groups.google.com/group/heroku/

Comment: Show us the 3rd line of `myapplication.rb`.

Comment: Nakilon, it is mentioned in the post. The 3rd line is "require 'models'" where a models.rb file exists in the same directory as myapplication.rb. I was thinking of just folding the models.rb file into the myapplication.rb file for this example application, but I don't really think that solves the problem.

Comment: Does it run on your local machine? FYI, Heroku recommends using Bundler and Gemfile, not .gems. See http://docs.heroku.com/bundler.

Comment: Steve, the application does run okay on my local machine - I have not used Bundler and Gemfile (as I mentioned I am new to the ruby world) - I will look into these options, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem, so this is not a full answer, but perhaps it will help. If you simply used `heroku logs`, you only get something like 20 (or perhaps it's 50) lines of output. Your error trace does not look like it starts from the actual error, since it begins "from" which, in my limited experience, indicates that it's not the source. If you haven't already, try `heroku logs -n 200` or more to get a longer trace, and search for "Errno" or "ERROR" and so on. It won't help with the console issue, but at least it might tell you why your app is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on one of the Heroku stacks that uses Ruby 1.9.x (as opposed to the older 1.8.x) versions of Ruby, be aware of the new "require_relative" directive with 1.9, which you must use to reference files in paths relative to your current file.

This tripped me up, because I was locally developing with 1.8.x

If you want it to work for both 1.8.x and 1.9.x, you could do something like:

```
require "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/another_referenced_rb_file_in_same_directory"
```